# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ppn

Tags: android, android-animation, android-library

Got this error from crashlytics report. only happened on android api level <= 19 or 4.x.x. 
full crashlytics report: http://crashes.to/s/39cf63dd2ef

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ppn
   at ppm.(SourceFile:2)
   at ppk.onAnimationEnd(SourceFile:10)
   at android.animation.AnimatorSet$AnimatorSetListener.onAnimationEnd(AnimatorSet.java:765)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1012)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.access$400(ValueAnimator.java:51)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:623)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:639)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:547)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I already created issue report on google. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73595289.

Any help to fix this error, please? I dont believe google team will solve this issue fast enough, and my application users will be keep getting this error.

Comment: did you try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: hmm.. maybe I just need to add a row on proguard. thanks for the link, @Developer :D

Comment: Did you find a solution? @Dika

Comment: Did you use youtube player in your app ??

Comment: @GermainZ I only add this line in proguard:

-keep class android.animation.** { *; } # All classes in the com.example package

#####I've released the apk on playstore for 3 days and error didn't happen again. I'll wait for next week, then I will post that proguard line as answer.

Comment: @BiroNader yep I do use youtube player

Comment: @Dika check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674311/exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-pim

its a global issue with youtube API