# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError occured when playing video youtube in activity

Tags: android, youtube-api

can anyone help me to fix this issue, it comes when i start playing a youtube video in my activity in android :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: prg
                      at prf.<clinit>(SourceFile:2)
                      at prd.onAnimationEnd(SourceFile:10)
                      at android.animation.AnimatorSet$AnimatorSetListener.onAnimationEnd(AnimatorSet.java:818)
                      at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1056)
                      at android.animation.ValueAnimator.access$400(ValueAnimator.java:50)
                      at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:644)
                      at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:660)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've provided a trace. Without the code that it references we can only speculate as to what needs to be fixed. Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I disagree with the "put on hold" this is an android bug like we have millions of them on SOF. It should not be treated differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Bug on youtube android API, its only occurred in android 4.4 API 19
[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674311/exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-pim)

we are waiting for a solution from Google, I am using this [Android-YouTube-Player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/Android-YouTube-Player) now instead of official youtube API and its working good, actually its better than Youtube Official API

Comment: Thank you @BiroNader your solution works for me , tank you a lot

Comment: However i have a question,can you tell me  that this solution uses the youtube api or just some classes to display youtube video

Comment: just some classes, he makes his own player